# How to prevent a <div> element from being resized when zooming

Tags: html, css, web, resize, window

I'm building my website, and i have a problem with a div box.
I would like to find a way to freeze that div, so it cannot be resized when someone zoom in, but keep it always in the center, even if the window is resized.

I already have position fixed, and i tried using width and margin in px, with this code :

```
.wmenu {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
margin-left: -90px;
margin-top: -67px; 
background-color: rgb(13, 70, 155) ;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

But if i do that it will resize when someone zoom in.

So i tried that code, that froze the div, but doesn't keep the aspect ratio if i resize the window :

```
.wmenu {
position: fixed;
height: 28vh;
width: 13.5vw;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -4.9%;
margin-left: -6.7%;
background-color: rgb(13, 70, 155) ;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

How it should work when i resize the window :

[image: How it should work]

What happens :

[image: Glitch]

I tried to use vw and vh but it didn't seem to solve my problem :/
I searched a lot on internet but i can't find a way that work for me.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Set the width and height in units of `vw` and `vh` respectively.

Comment: Use of vw and vh do not solve my problem :/

Comment: Hi, show a minimal working example in order to help you better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a way to do that myself :

I was badly using the vw units.

I used the css code with the ratio problem, but with vw, which resize the height of the div in comparison with the width. So it always keeps the aspect ratio.

```
.wmenu {
position: fixed;
height: 14.5vw;
width: 14.5%;
top: 38.8%;
left: 42.75%;    
}
```

I also removed the margin, that was to center div, but it can create problem, such as the broken aspect ration. So i'm using top and left now.